# JDBC driver property setup failed

Tags: database, spring, database-connection, classpath, driver

I have a following problem:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested 
PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [org.postgresql.Driver]
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:101)
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:57)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
... 52 more
```

As for the POMs there are dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.0-801.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
```

What is more

```
postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar
```

appears both in classpath and lib folder of war package...

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the specific version you are using for the dependencies so that you can drill down the problem more easily. Furthermore, check the JDK compatibility.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>???</version>
    </dependency>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>???</version> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>???</version>
    </dependency>
```